# How to force host's DNS resolution to refresh for Hyper-V guest?

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I have multiple Hyper-V VMs, all using the default switch. The Host is Windows 10 and the guests are Windows and Linux.

When I save these VMs (i.e. hibernate them while they're running) and start them later, their IPs usually change.

The host keeps using their previous IP though, and I could not find a reliable way of forcing IP resolution to refresh. Flushing the DNS does not work. After some time, the name resolution from the host catches up with the ip of the guests, but I'd like to force this to happen manually.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you hibernate the VMs, they lose their DHCP lease on their IP addresses.

The only way for a VM to always keeps its IP address is to assign
it a static IP.
The exact way to do that depends on your local network architecture.

Comment: Thanks, but how is the host catching up with the new lease later? I was hoping whatever mechanism the host has that allows it to update the corresponding ip for the guest vm names can be triggered manually. Setting a static ip for the guests would work, but is it not possible to force to host to catch up quickly so to say?

Comment: Running Windows Explorer, Network section, may rescan the network.